# File not uploaded in specific path

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload file in specific path, unfortunately 2 warnings prevent me from finalizing the upload :/

**mkdir(): No such file or directory in**

**move_uploaded_file(Candidatures/xxxx/index.jpeg): failed to open stream:**

What I am doing wrong??

```
$uploadState = "";
if(!empty($_FILES['upload_CoveringLetter']))
{
    $uploadState = 1;
    $file_name = $_FILES['upload_CoveringLetter']['name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['upload_CoveringLetter']['size'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['upload_CoveringLetter']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['upload_CoveringLetter']['type'];
    $file_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['upload_CoveringLetter']['name'])));

    $extensions = array("odt","doc","docx","pdf","jpeg", "jpg");
    if(in_array($file_ext, $extensions) === false)
    {
         $uploadState = 0;
         header('Location: ../addCandidacy.php');
    }
    else
    {
        if(!file_exists("Candidatures/".$Candidacy['candidacyType']) && !is_dir("Candidatures/".$Candidacy['candidacyType']))
        {
            mkdir("Candidatures/".$Candidacy['candidacyType']);
        }
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "Candidatures/".$Candidacy['candidacyType']."/".$file_name);
        $Candidacy['upload_CoveringLetter'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having error in your code

```
mkdir("Candidatures/".$Candidacy['candidacyType']);
```

It should be

```
mkdir('Candidatures/'.$Candidacy['candidacyType'],0777, true);
```

Comment: Provided your solution to my problem, and that solved it! thx @Avi How can I get now all the directory of uploaded file?? I tried with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], but I only get the beginning of the directory : /var/www/Candidature and not :var/www/Candidature/Candidatures/xxx/index.jpeg